# How can I retrieve Stripe payment information after succesfull payment?

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe Controller

```php
   \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(config('stripe.sk'));

        $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
            'payment_method_types' => ['ideal'],
            'line_items' => [
                [
                    'price_data' => [
                        'currency' => 'eur',
                        'product_data' => [
                            'name' => ''. $inputName .' - '. $inputSize .'',
                        ],
                        'unit_amount' => ''. $inputPrice . '00',
                    ],
                    'quantity' => 1,
                ],
            ],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => route('success',$locale=session('locale')),
            'cancel_url' => route('failed', $locale=session('locale')),
        ]);

        return redirect()->away($session->url);
    }
```

How can I get the payment ID from this transaction?

I have tried using $session->id but it comes back with an error.

Comment: What's the error you're seeing, and what are you planning to use the ID for? Normally it's recommended to use webhooks to get notified when the payment is completed successfully: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Comment: @vanya want to add the payment ID in my database with the corresponding order.

Comment: @vanya I'm trying to retreive it from the session, but that doesn't work. So the error I get is that there is no such $id.

Comment: Could you please copy the exact wording of the error or a add a screenshot?

Comment: Added a webhook. I'm now able to receive the `case 'checkout.session.completed': $session = $event->data->object;`. How can I get information out of that so I can pass it on to my database?

Comment: Have you tried `$event->data->object->id`?